# IndexOutOfBoundsException error using LibGDX Arrays

Tags: java, arraylist, libgdx

I keep getting an error when running my shuffle method. Below is my shuffle method. Im coding in java using LibGDX and shuffling an array list.

```
public Array<Card> shuffle(){    
    for (int i = 0; i < deckOne.size; i++) {
        int length = deckOne.size;
        int random = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * length);

        Card c = deckOne.removeIndex(random);
        Card temp = deckOne.removeIndex(i);
        deckOne.insert(i, c);
        deckOne.insert(random, temp);    
    }
    return deckOne;
}
```

I then go and call this method in my main game:  `deckOne.shuffle();`

This error appears

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index can't be >= size: 19 >= 19
at com.battleforbronze.game.Model.Deck1.shuffle(Deck1.java:57)
```

My question is how to fix this error. Most other questions i've seen about this topic say that `int i = 0` must have been `int i = 1`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Abdelhak `Card temp = deckOne.removeIndex(i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
int random = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
```

produces a random integer from 0 to length **inclusive**, so if the max value is chosen (`length`), it is too big an index for your array, since the index starts at zero. So either subtract 1: `(int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (length - 1))`, or use the built-in LibGDX function, which returns a random integer from 0 to length **exclusive**:

```
int random = MathUtils.random(length);
```

But there is another issue. You remove two cards from the deck, and then insert them using indices that were acquired before you shrunk the array. When you get to the end of the deck (i == length - 1), when you try to insert the new card, its index is too big for the now smaller array (which now has a size of length - 2).

There is already a convenience method for what you're trying to do in the last four lines of your loop:

```
deckone.swap(i, random);
```

Actually, there's already a convenience method for shuffling an entire array so your entire method could be replaced with

```
deckone.shuffle();
```

Comment: I tried both but the IndexOutOfBoundsException still occurs

Comment: I edited the answer. There's a second issue with your code.

Comment: the `deckOne.shuffle();` does not work, I have tried it many times but never seems to work.

Comment: Then there is something else wrong with your code outside this method. You'll have to share your code for how you instantiate all the cards and what exactly "doesn't work" means.

Comment: I tried `deckOne.swap(i, random);` and it work perfectly! Thanks!